# What -a argument do in ksh?

Tags: shell, ksh

Hi this is a piece of code

```
if [ -a $OUT ]
then
rotate $OUT
fi
```

i am new to shell script and not getting what -a is doing there and when i remove a it's throw an error argument accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The construct `[ -a $OUT ]` is a way how to check whether a file/directory `$OUT` exists. If so it returns 0 (true) otherwise 1 (false). You can rewrite it with `test` build-in/system command like

```
if test -a $OUT; then
    rotate $OUT
fi
```

Check `help test` for more details and additional unary/binary operators.

Answer (score 1):

`-a` is obsolete and confusing as it is colliding with the legacy "and" operator (now obsoleted by combining `test` statements with `&&`).

`-e` should be used instead for testing if a file exists.

Comment: +1 Note that POSIX has also deprecated using `-a` in favor of combining two `test` commands with `&&`, so `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead of `[ ... -a ...]`.